# Find steam games folder

Tags: vb.net, steam

How can I get to a Steam game folder without hardcoding it?

Instead of hardcoding `C:\Steam\steamapps\common\<game_folder>\GameData` in my code can I use something involving the `steamappid` of a game to obtain this information automatically?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In order to obtain a Steam games folder you have to follow this steps:

1. find Steam installation folder
2. check Steam `acf` files and `libraryfolders.vdf`

You can find Steam `InstallPath` in windows registry:

- 32-bit: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Valve\Steam`
- 64-bit: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\Steam`

You can [read a Value from a Registry Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz88758e.aspx) using this code:

```
Dim strSteamInstallPath as String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Valve\Steam", "InstallPath", Nothing)

MsgBox("The install path is " & strSteamInstallPath)
```

Once you have Steam main folder (the one containing `steam.exe`) you can read games installation folder from `appmanifest_<steamappid>.acf` files contained in `\steamapps` subfolder.

For example, `appmanifest_2280.acf` contains informations about `Ultimate Doom`.

You can search for a particular `steamappid` or analyze every files and get game name from `name` key.

Also check `libraryfolders.vdf` in `\steamapps` subfolder for other game installation folders.

For example I have some games in `D:\mygames` so my `libraryfolders.vdf` is:

```
"LibraryFolders"
{
    "TimeNextStatsReport"   "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    "ContentStatsID"        "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    "1"                     "D:\\mygames"
}
```

Once you have this alternative folder, check for `acm` files contained in `\steamapps` subfolder.

Comment: FORGET THAT! I just needed to add \Steam to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\  , and now it pops up. THANK YOU MY GOOD SIR! Could you edit your answer to this? And ill mark it as the answer :)

Comment: answer updated. sorry but I don't have steam installed so I can't test the registry key I find on steam faq.

Comment: No worries, at all man. It is working beautifully. Thank you

Comment: May I ask the exact applicability of this answer? The original question was about the game folder, does this refer to that folder or to the application folder? Can this folder be changed by the user? if so, is this registry entry being updated accordingly? That is: is this surely a reliable way to know the games folder for Steam under the most likely conditions? If this is a reliable enough answer, the whole question might not be completely off-topic (+ useful for someone else).

Comment: @varocarbas This is good enough for me to work further with. It shows where Steam is located. In my case: `C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam` and then i add `\steamapps\common\*game*\gamedata` to pinpoint the game folders location. Though now ive got another problem. Ive got another steam games folder on my ssd  I:\  which, no, it does not update. But this definitely helped me to understand how to do it, and now ive got another goal, which i will be taking on.

Comment: @Thomsen1707 Happy to read that all this helped you. But I wanted to clarify the exact applicability of this answer to the original question "how to locate the games folder?", mainly for future readers. I guess that your last comment is clear enough on this front.

Comment: @varocarbas Yea, it basicly gives out the place where Steam was originally installed. Mine was installed on the C:\ drive in the `Program Files(x86)` folder. So instead of hardcoding `C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\*game*\gamedata`. You would create a variable with the registry placement, and then use it to show the specific users path to the Steam folder. E.g.  `Variable & "\steamapps\common\*game*\gamedata"`

Comment: @Thomsen1707 Some people like me have multiple folders where games can be installed.  I have a rather small SSD on my laptop as my main drive and a larger and slower drive.  I put a few games I play often on my C: drive and have another library folder on my D: drive for games that are very larger or that I don't play often.  In that case you would need to look deeper and parse `libraryfolders.vdf`