# Getting full folder path from name

Tags: c#, cross-platform

I am trying to find the full path of a folder from just the name of the folder.
The folder in question is advdupe2 folder that is usually situated in `\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\GarrysMod\garrysmod\data\advdupe2` but people might have the SteamLibrary folder in different locations for example i have it on `D:\steam\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\GarrysMod\garrysmod\data\advdupe2` and it is by default on `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\`.
I have tried searching for this everywhere but i can find no references to this.

I looking for something like `string folderPath = findFolder(folderName);`

Comment: Have you made any attempts at it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please clarify if it's only that exact example where you need to find the steam game installation path or if you need to find a "random" folder on your computer? If it's only steam games, there may be better ways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find steam games folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090258/find-steam-games-folder)

Comment: What if you have more than one folders with the same name? For advdupe2 there might not be, but for a general solution this is a possibility.

Comment: It seems that, on the face of it, you're specifically looking for a known location within the steam folder, hence the suggested duplicate is relevant. If you're looking for a general solution, let me know and I'll retract the close vote. To find a subfolder within a main folder, you can use [Directory.EnumerateDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories?view=net-6.0) specifying the pattern describing the name of the folder you're looking for

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica Im not sure that can be duplicated for linux though :/

Comment: @mcy If i add for example \common\GarrysMod\garrysmod\data\advdupe2 to searching it might work better

Comment: @Ee0Rk Please add that information to your question. You only tagged it as C#, no editor, no OS, no .Net Core or sth.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan No im not good enough at c# for that, i tried my best at making some tries but no it didnt go well